# Rasterio to convert a GeoTIFF into a GeoJSON in Python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, rasterio

I am currently working in Python and would like to convert a raster GeoTIFF into a GeoJSON.

(I am currently working with Jupiter notebook and ipyleaflet - they only display data as a GeoJSON and not as a GeoTIFF).

I came across rasterio which allows you to read in rasters and also do various oparations. However, I can't manage to export the data as GeoJSON. What kind of tool can I use here? Or is it possibly not possible at all? I found an tool for writing data and the [documentation](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/writing.html) says that you can also use some GDAL function. But they don't show any examples at all...

Comment: A GeoTIFF is a raster format, while geojson is a vector format, so your question does not make much sense.

Comment: Well, if pixels are considered to be small rectangular polygons they can be converted into vectors with for example https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_polygonize.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ian Turton points out, GeoJSON files can represent vector data, not raster data. In principle, you could first vectorize the raster data to polygons, and then save these as GeoJSON. But that is only useful if a exceptional cases (a raster with very few cells) as this generally creates very large datasets / files that would be very cumbersome to use; if they can be used at all.

A quick search suggests that you may be able to use the ImageOverlay method or other tricks in ipyleaflet to add raster data (png images).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I somehow overlooked that..